# How do I set the horizontal gap for just one part of a FlowLayout?

Tags: java, swing, flowlayout

I have a flow layout with three buttons, between the first and second buttons I would like a horizontal gap of 30 and between the second and third buttons I would like a horizontal gap of 10.  I tried this:

```
Jpanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JButton button1 = new Button("1");
JButton button2 = new Button("2");
JButton button3 = new Button("3");

panel.add(button1);
((FlowLayout)panel.getLayout()).setHgap(30);
panel.add(button2);
((FlowLayout)panel.getLayout()).setHgap(10);
panel.add(button3);
```

But this changes all of the Horizontal gaps to 10.

Any ideas would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `EmptyBorder` to the 2nd button, with the additional pixels in the second parameter (`left`):

```
button2.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 0));
```

Comment: If this is actually a button and you set the border on the button, in Java 8, doing this makes the button background disappear.

Comment: @Evan put the button into a panel, then set the empty border to the panel.

Answer (score 11):

try to use Box.createHorizontalStrut

```
panel.add(button1);
panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));
panel.add(button2);
panel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
panel.add(button3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try MigLayout:

```
Jpanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout());

panel.add(new Button("1"), "gap right 30");
panel.add(new Button("2"), "gap right 10");
panel.add(new Button("3"));
```

Comment: MigLayout sounds like something that would be effective but I can only use java awt layouts.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative solution would be to use a `createRigidArea(...)` which creates an invisible component that's always the specified size. Such component can then be used as a spacer:

```
panel.add(button1);
panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(30, 0)));
panel.add(button2);
panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
panel.add(button3);
```